# How to get out from sub folder & reach to main folder using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which it loops in sub folder & fetches data from word document. But after looping and reaching the last document in sub folder, control is not going back to main folder & then next subfolder. Please see my code. Help me where I am making wrong.

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim strFolderName As String
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim FileToOpen As String

Sub FindFilesInSubFolders()
    Dim fsoFolder As Scripting.Folder

    FileToOpen = "*v2.1.doc*"

    If FSO Is Nothing Then
       Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    End If

    'Set the parent folder for the new subfolders

    strFolderName = "C:\Test"
    Set fsoFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strFolderName)
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    OpenFilesInSubFolders fsoFolder
    wrdApp.Quit
End Sub

Sub OpenFilesInSubFolders(fsoPFolder As Scripting.Folder)
    Dim fsoSFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim fileDoc As Scripting.File

    For Each fsoSFolder In fsoPFolder.SubFolders

        For Each fileDoc In fsoSFolder.Files
            If fileDoc.Name Like FileToOpen Then
            Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileDoc.Path)
            With wrdApp
               .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
               .Selection.Copy
               ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
           End With
           wrdDoc.Close False
           'wrdApp.Quit
           End If
       Next fileDoc

       OpenFilesInSubFolders fsoSFolder
    Next fsoSFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried the `.parentfolder` property?

Comment: I haven't tried .parentfolder property Raystafarian. Can you please tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit so it would run on my Office Word 2007, and it ran wonderfully... Below is the minimal loop to traverse all folders.

Note also that you forget to process the files of the folder in the first call to `OpenFilesInSubFolders`.

```
Dim wrdApp As Object
Dim FileToOpen As String

Sub FindFilesInSubFolders()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim strFolderName As String
Dim FileToOpen As String
Dim fsoFolder As Object

    FileToOpen = "*v2.1.doc*"

    If FSO Is Nothing Then
       Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    End If
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Set the parent folder for the new subfolders

    strFolderName = "C:\test"
    Set fsoFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strFolderName)

    OpenFilesInSubFolders fsoFolder
 End Sub

Sub OpenFilesInSubFolders(fsoFolder As Object)
Dim fsoSFolder As Object
Dim fileDoc As Object
Dim wrdDoc As Object
    '
    ' First process the files of the curent directory, ...
    '
    For Each fileDoc In fsoFolder.Files
        If fileDoc.Name Like FileToOpen Then
            Debug.Print fileDoc.Path
            Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileDoc.Path)
            With wrdApp
            .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
                .Selection.Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
            wrdDoc.Close False
        End If
    Next fileDoc
    '
    ' ...then process all subdirectories
    '
    For Each fsoSFolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
        OpenFilesInSubFolders fsoSFolder
    Next fsoSFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: Paul, I tried to fetch table data from word document from sub-folder. But failing to read that word document. Below is my "Sub OpenFilesInSubFolders(fsoPFolder As Object) " code part.

Comment: For Each fileDoc In fsoSFolder.Files
            If fileDoc.Name Like FileToOpen Then
            Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileDoc.Path)
            With wrdApp
               .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
               .Selection.Copy
               ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
           End With
           wrdDoc.Close False
           'wrdApp.Quit
           End If

Comment: (cont)
Next fileDoc
       Debug.Print fsoSFolder
       OpenFilesInSubFolders fsoSFolder

    Next fsoSFolder
End Sub

Comment: You are trying to open the Path. You must use the `Name` property (possibly prepended by the `Path` property).

Comment: The logic of your `OpenFilesInSubFolders` is wrong. You never process the first parent directory. I will edit my answer to show you. And you must start using the debugger. You could have caught this error yourself!

Comment: after reading all the word documents in a sub-folder, it is reading for a word document starting with "~$......doc" which I don't have it in my path. So, it is now reading only one sub-folder in my OpenFilesInSubFolders logic. Can you give me the correct one please.

Comment: Probably a hidden file. If it opens the file, then it is there and meets your filespec.Use a debugger, adapt your FileToOpen, check for a $ sign or whatever. I am not your code monkey.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just search the directory using windows shell and iterate through the output instead?

```
Sub SO()

Dim files As Variant, file As Variant

files = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR ""C:\test\*v2.1.doc*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll,vbCrLf), ".")

For Each file In files
    Debug.Print CStr(file)
Next

End Sub
```

No need to loop through all the folders, just get the files in one hit.